# Azure Language Studio not showing text content in python script regarding OCR

Tags: python, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on OCR of a word document to recognize the content mentioned in the document. I observed that OCR generated python code is not showing the content available in the document in auto-generated python script in language studio. I just want to get the python script structure where I can see the tags which are focusing on the identifying the sentences without table content.

Is the approach I am looking for is right? Any flow that explains requirement is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This problem will be defined in Form Recognizer. In this factor, we cannot see anything related to the general text from an image or a text file like **DOCX and PDF** in **python script** which will be generated. The form recognition, related to the specific structure that is having pre-modelled scenarios of syntax. But the content which was mentioned as the input without any tabular form is **not recognized in python**. The content will be visible in **JSON** which is other than the tabular form.

Check out the thread for reference.

[Azure Cognitive Form Recognizer to Extract Page Numbers using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72546522/azure-cognitive-form-recognizer-to-extract-page-numbers-using-python/72555682#72555682)

Comment: I checked the link shared and works for me. Thanks for the reply.